# Dell printer asks me to load MP Feeder whenever I try to print

Tags: printer

My Dell B54670dn asks me to "load MP Feeder with Custom Type 6 Letter" (or plain paper letter if I change the MP "type" to that in the printer settings) whenever I try to print.

The default tray is Tray 1, and it is loaded with letter.

I can force the print to continue with Tray 1, but I have to manually do that each time I print.

(The print job is bone-simple; all defaults, letter size page).

The printer used to work just fine. As far as I know, no settings have changed.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Check the default settings. Also check if the sensor switch for paper is faulty (sometimes it just needs to be wiggled -- paper dust gets in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: in my case it was a hardware failure: the tray's gearing underneath the paper-sizing slider is apparently broken. Even with the size locked in to "LTR", the printer still sees the tray as "Universal" only. When I replaced that paper tray with one from another printer, it worked right away.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the printer is being asked to print on a custom paper size, "Custom Type 6 Letter". This is almost certainly a driver setting.

Here are couple of things to check.

1. Check the Paper Type setting (plain, letterhead, card, etc) in the driver. If it is anything except Plain Paper, most printers will only accept it from the MPF. This is most likely your problem: I suspect the selected paper size is "Custom Type 6 Letter"
2. Check that the sliders in the tray are butted up against the paper. They tell the printer the size of the paper.
3. If you are printing from Word, check the paper size and tray setting  in Page Setup. Go to Page Layout, click the little arrow at the bottom right of the Page Setup area. Word ignores printer settings (except that a new document is created with the settings of the currently selected printer). This means that a document that was created for a different printer, may cause problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comments: 1, the print job only asks for letter. No custom paper type. The "type 6" comes only from the printer settings. Changing the printer settings on MP changes what the printer requests to load, indicating that this is not the problem. 2. Yep. It's locked into "letter". 3. Printing from anything: paper size is set to letter.

Answer (score 0):

The Load MP Feeder message indicates that the printer wants you to load paper. The letter suggests 8½ x 11″ usual US size. You could either re-send the file calling for Plain Letter or put some plain paper in the MP tray and program it for custom type 6.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. But as I said, all parts of the pipeline are for plain paper letter, and the default tray is loaded with plain paper letter.